# Heroku fails to scale, no status, log shows 413

Tags: heroku

Could anyone please help with Heroku's guide of "getting started with java":
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java

It works fine with scale=1
But it fails when I try to scale up, eg:

```
heroku ps:scale web=2 --app myap
```

This responds "internal server error" and asks to run "heroku status".
However "heroku status" just says "no knows issues at this time".
And "heroku:logs" doesn't give much info, except perhaps some "413" error:

```
2013-12-19T06:42:53+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-12-19T06:42:53.947859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-12-19T06:42:57.590970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-12-19T06:42:58.225911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* HelloWorld`
2013-12-19T06:42:59.363034+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2013-12-19T06:42:59.677493+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-19 06:42:59.675:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.0.v20120127
2013-12-19T06:42:59.752285+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-19 06:42:59.751:INFO:oejsh.
ContextHandler:started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2013-12-19T06:42:59.795692+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-19 06:42:59.787:INFO:oejs.A
bstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:37683
2013-12-19T06:42:59.936719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-12-19T06:43:00.226719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
```

Help would be appreciated,
thanks very much

Comment: Your application is crashing, and the reason isn't clear since you don't have any debug information. Try lowering your applications debug level to something that provides more information.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately I don't see more data when I try to change the log. Could I be doing it wrong? "heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"

Comment: Check which logging framework is being used in your app (java.util.logging or log4j or whatever) and see how you set the level. I'm not sure a simple env var will suffice.

Comment: I'll check, anyway thanks very much for replying and trying to help :)

Comment: For the record, it turns out I was using a free account, which won't allow to scale. Unfortunately they didn't bother to put a readable error message for this. But thanks for the help